# How to echo a clickable href to another file in php

Tags: php, html

Im new to php and i am trying study how to design web page, the code is not mine. My problem is , i have some clickable done using a table for that i have an array

```
$buttons=array('Home'=>'home.php', 
              'Contact'=>'contact.php',
              'Services'=>'service.php',
              'Site map'=> 'map.php');
```

and there is a function

```
function DisplayMenu($buttons)
 {
   echo "<table width='100%' bgcolor 
    ='white' cellpadding='4' 
    cellspacing='4'\n";
    echo "<tr>\n";
$width =100/count($buttons);
while (list($name, $url)=each ($buttons))
{
   $this-> DisplayButton($width, $name, 
   $url);
 }

   echo "</tr>\n";
   echo "</table>\n";
}
```

and for displaying the button there is also a function

```
function DisplayButton($width, $name, $url)
{
    echo " <td width='$width%'>
           <a herf ='".$url."'>
           <img src= 'ab.jpg' alt='$name' 
           border='0'> 
           </a> <a herf='".$url."'><span 
           class ='menu'> 
           ".$name."</span></a></td>";       
  }
```

My problem is when i click for example the home button its not taking me to the home.php page , can someone help me ?

Comment: It's `href` and not `herf`

Comment: the DisplayButton($width, $name, $url) has 3 parameters, you are passing 4. there is a blanck space in method call : $this-> DisplayButton (im not sure thats works). I recommend replace this complex loop while (list($name, $url)=each ($buttons))  whith this foreach ($buttons as $name => $url)

Comment: And finally, if your button not works, check your resulting html. Is correct?

Comment: thanks Curlas, the code works fine , i just took the functions i needed just trying to make it simple, the argument !$this->isURLCurrentPage($url) u can ignore that .....thanks so much but i will check

Comment: Did @DarkBee comment provide the answer?

Comment: np if you are new but you should more read & learn than ask for basic problems. You need more fight with your code to get skill.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Just a typo** (herf to href)

```
function DisplayButton($width, $name, $url)
{
    echo "
        <td width='{$width}%'>
            <a href='{$url}'>
                <img src='ab.jpg' alt='{$name}' border='0'> 
            </a>
            <a href='{$url}'>
                <span class='menu'>{$name}</span>
            </a>
        </td>
    ";
}
```

Comment: that was very help full, its working now thanks Remco k